# Inheritance, pure virtual functions and non-inline member function definitions

Tags: c++, inheritance, unresolved-external, pure-virtual

I have boiled down my issue to the following code all in a single *.cpp file:

```
class A {
public:
    A() {};

    int PerformAction() {
        return Action();
    }

protected:
    virtual int Action();
}

class B: public A {
protected:
    int Action();
}

int B::Action() {
   return 4;
}

int main() {
    B newB;
    newB.PerformAction();
};
```

The previous code throws an `Unresolved external symbol error on B::Action()`. Changing `a::Action()`'s definition to:

```
virtual int Action() = 0;
```

yields instead the `Cannot instantiate abstract class` compiler error where it is used in the main function. All of the answers I have seen relate to having the code spread across multiple files, but this is occurring all within one source file. I imagine it is related to `B`'s implementation of `Action()` being outside the class definition of `B` but can't see any reason why it should cause any error.

Comment: This clearly isn't the code you're compiling - the missing semicolons and attempt to call a protected function will give compiler errors before the linker error you report. Once I fix those errors, and make the function pure virtual as you describe, there is no error: http://ideone.com/IS7PJj

Comment: Also, please don't add line numbers to posted code; it's a pain having to remove them in order to test it.

Comment: Also, `main` must return `int`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour apologies for the line numbers, I wanted to make clear it was a single file and not code scattered around many, avoiding answers relating to such. Removed. The calling of a protected member function, made that closer to reality for you. The code was really trying to capture the essence of the problem rather than be compilable necessarily. I am looking more for relationships between the above definition structure, its usage usage and the observed errors, less for a syntactic evaluation.

Comment: In order to understand why you get the error, we'll need code that demonstrates the error. This code has different errors (missing semicolons, and wrong type for `main`), and compiles cleanly after fixing those. There's no way to know what might be wrong with your code. Presumably it's doing something that tries to instantiate `A`,  but beyond that I can't guess.

Comment: Please **do not** "try to capture the essence" of the problem, reduce the problem to **real** code that shows the real problem, not something that smells a bit like it when you squint hard enough. The relationships between the above definition structure are not the same as in your real code, so are irrelevant.

Comment: The difficulty of what code to provide seems to be the balance between a few things. A lot of code can be proprietary and not shown exactly. Some code is too long and obscure to really make sense of. Code like that then makes any answers less applicable to others reading the same question and attempting to get value from the answer. I tend to prefer generic code that is interpreted neurally rather than long-winded code that needs to be cut-paste-compiled.

Comment: So reduce it to code that exhibits the same errors. The code above doesn't even exhibit the errors you claimed it does. At the very least, try to compile/link/run the code you're posting here, and report the errors from that actual code, not some other code you're not showing us.

Comment: Style aside, the question as posed garnered me exactly the answer I needed and will hopefully help others facing the same question. Adding to my previous comment, sometimes it's not possible to boil down the code to a meaningful chunk that definitely exhibits the problem, simply because that implies knowing where the problem is. If that were always possible then the question would probably become redundant. Anyways I'd prefer not to argue about style, we're just different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error messages, taken together, indicate a signature mismatch between `A::Action` and `B::Action`, such that `B::Action` does not become an overrider.  The signatures must match perfectly (including *cv-qualification* of `this`), except that return type covariance is allowed.

And `B::Action` must be `virtual`.  It will be implicitly if the signature matches, unless it is a template.  Templates can't override.

If you have a C++11 compiler, I suggest using the `override` keyword, to make signature mismatch a compile error.

Comment: Beautiful, this was the hint I needed. I am using VC++ Express 2008, not sure what compiler is inside it. The problem was some unnecessary callings of template<typename ... > on the function implementations making them not truly overrides.

Comment: @JCollins: Template functions are never virtual, so that does sound like your problem.

Comment: That's what I'm learning. Fortunately with that the problem is solved and I can compile just fine now. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

> The previous code throws an Unresolved external symbol error on `B::Action()`.

Indeed, all non-pure virtual functions must be defined, so that their address can be stored in the virtual function table for the class.

> yields instead the Cannot instantiate abstract class compiler error

No it doesn't: http://ideone.com/IS7PJj

You'd get that error if you tried to directly instantiate `A`, or a subclass which didn't override the pure virtual function. `B` does override it, and so is not abstract.

Possibly, your real class `B` has an incorrect signature for `Action`, so it doesn't actually override the one declared in `A`. In C++11, you can add the `override` specifier to the one in `B`, to get a more helpful error message in that case.

> I imagine it is related to `B`'s implementation of `Action()` being outside the class definition of `B`

No, that shouldn't be an issue, as long as there's exactly one definition of the function.

Comment: I guess that is my confusion, in my code B definitely implements Action(), (or it's real-world equivalent,) though am still receiving that error. I believe what you're saying is, look somewhere else for the issue because it is not a function of that particular choice of structure and usage.

Comment: `Indeed, all non-pure virtual functions must be defined, so that their address can be stored in the virtual function table for the class.` And, more abstractly, so that they can be invoked!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes; but (unlike most functions) they must be defined even if not invoked.